# Объединение данных двух таблиц по общему значению ячейки

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet, google-docs, google-docs-api

Есть таблица с двумя листами в Google Docs. Как объединить их данные по общему полю "Артикул" при совпадении значений? Т.е если в обоих таблицах есть общий артикул "BL001" то задача их объединить. Моя попытка решения заключалась в использовании =IMPORTRANGE("google_docs_url"; "Лист2!A1:D4") но она не производит сопоставление SKU

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате нужно получить такую таблицу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На форуме принято помогать, а не делать чужую работу. Поэтому, если  Вы хотите, что Вами кто-то занялся, нужно приложить свою попытку решения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Моя попытка решения заключалась в использовании =IMPORTRANGE("google_docs_url"; "Лист2!A1:D4") но она не производит сопоставление SKU.

Comment: Добавьте Ваш комментарий в текст вопроса\

Comment: Добавил комментарий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные подтягивать с помощью функции  *ВПР (VLOOKUP)*

```
=ВПР(артикул;диапазон_второго_листа;столбец;0)
```

*артикул* - ссылка на ячейку с артикулом в этой строке;

*диапазон_второго_листа* - диапазон, первый столбец которого содержит артикулы;

*столбец* - номер столбца с нужными данными (номер считается от столбца с артикулами);

*0* указывает на поиск точного соответствия артикула.

Формулу можно сделать протягиваемую для всех четырех столбцов, закрепив диапазоны в нужных местах:

```
=ВПР($A2;Лист2!$A$2:$D$25;СТОЛБЕЦ(B1);0)
```

Но при небольшом количестве столбцов не составит труда копировать формулу и указать номер столбца константой (2, 3 или 4)

Comment: @Ask, если Вы удовлетворены ответом, не забудьте поставить ему "зеленую галочку"